# Некорректно работает кнопка редактировать

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с проблемой,что существует три кнопки редактирования в разных столбцах,но при нажатии на любую из них,всегда редактируется первый из них. Надеюсь более менее понятно объяснил)

```
const editBtn = document.createElement('button'); 
   editBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Edit')); 
   editBtn.classList.add('board__edit'); 
   editBtn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    const items = document.querySelector('.board__stage-card'); 
     
    if (editBtn.textContent == 'Edit') { 
     editBtn.textContent = 'Ok'; 
     items.contentEditable = true; 
     items.focus(); 
    } 
    else { 
     editBtn.textContent = 'Edit'; 
     items.contentEditable = false; 
    } 
     
   } );
```

Comment: Добавьте html любого столбца

Comment: `querySelector` выбирает из DOM только один элемент (самый первый из подходящих) - для выборки нескольких элементов, используют `querySelectorAll`. Но тут уместнее использовать делегирование обработки событий и уникальные data-атрибуты (в них можно и селектор записывать), чем усложнять логику циклами / поисками индекса в коллекции.